# Edit Log4Net properties in Web.Config file using powershell

Tags: xml, powershell, web-config, log4net, web.config-transform

During my CI build I am using PowerShell to edit some values in a Web.Config file.

I have used the following code to do achieve this;

```
#Open web.config
$xml = [xml](get-content($ConfigurationFile))
$conf = $xml.configuration  
$conf.appSettings.add | foreach { if ($_.key -eq "ApplicationRootUri") { $_.value = $ApplicationSettingValue } }  
$conf.appSettings.add | foreach { if ($_.key -eq "connectionString") { $_.value = $MainConnectionStringValue } }
#Save Config
$xml.Save($ConfigurationFile)
```

However the next property I need to change is not in the AppSettings part of the config file. It's in the Log4App;

```
<log4net>
  <appender name="AdoNetAppender" type="log4net.Appender.AdoNetAppender">
  <bufferSize value="1" />
  <connectionType value="System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection, System.Data, Version=1.0.3300.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
  <connectionString value="VALUE_I_WANT_TO_CHANGE" />
</log4net>
```

I've tried various ways of changing this value with no luck so far.

What I've stalled at carries on from the above code;

```
$confLog = $conf.log4net.appender
$$confLog.add | foreach { if ($_.name -eq "AdoNetAppender") { $_.connectionString.value = $MainConnectionStringValue } }
```

Error message I'm getting is normally along the lines of 'The property |'connectionString|' cannot be found on this object. Verify that the property exists and can be set'

Anyone know how to correctly edit the connectionString property?

Comment: Not an answer, but you can set the connectionString**Name** in the log4net config and it will retrieve the value from the web.config - as you seem to be using `MainConnectionStringValue` for both?

Comment: Hi @stuartd, how would I go about doing that? Yes MainConnectionStringValue should be used for both connection strings.

Comment: I hadn't noticed you have your connection string in the app settings section, this only works if you have it in a `<connectionStrings>` section. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone who is interested, I was so close yet so far away

Here is what I've put together which eventually worked for me

```
$confLog = $conf.log4net.appender
$confLog | foreach { if ($_.name -eq "AdoNetAppender") { $_.connectionString.Value = $MainConnectionStringValue } }
```